# Select all records for customers where mindate in 2015

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, mindate

I want to select all records for customers whose first order is from 2015. I want any orders they placed after 2015 too, but I DON'T want the records for customers whose first order was in 2016. I am ultimately trying to find the percentage of people who order more than twice, but I want to exclude the customers who were new in 2016.

This doesn't work because 'mindate' is an invalid column name but I'm not sure why or how else to try it.

```
Select 
    od.CustomerID, OrderID, OrderDSC, OrderDTS 
From 
    OrderDetail OD
Join 
    (Select 
         OrderID, Min(orderdts) as mindate
     From 
         OrderDetail
     Where  
         mindate Between '2015-1-1' and '2015-12-31'
     Group By Orderid) b on od.OrderID = b.OrderID
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `execution phases` - it's seqency how is qry evaluated and by engine. In where clause your mindate not yet exists.

You can change mindate by orderdts:

```
select OrderID, min(orderdts) as mindate
from OrderDetail
where orderdts between '2015-1-1' and '2015-12-31'
group by Orderid
```

Second option is to use `having` statement - it's evaluated after `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

What I di was select the distinct CustomerIDs that fall in between your daterange and did a left join with the table so it filters out anyone that doesn't fall in between your daterange.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (Select DISTINCT(CustomerID) as CustomerID 
        FROM OrderDetail WHERE OrderDTS between '2015-1-1' AND '2015-12-31')  oIDs

LEFT JOIN

    OrderDetail OD

ON oIDs.CustomerID = OD.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the EXISTS clause.  It is basically a sub-query.  Below is an example you should be able to adapt.

```
create table Test (Id int, aDate datetime)

insert Test values (1,'04/04/2014')
insert Test values (1,'05/05/2015')
insert Test values (1,'06/06/2016')
insert Test values (2,'04/30/2016')
insert Test values (3,'02/27/2014')


select t.* from Test t 
where
  aDate>='01/01/2015'
  and exists(select * from Test x where x.Id=t.Id and x.aDate >='01/01/2015' and x.aDate<'01/01/2016')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the orderdts data type but if it is datetime orders on 2015-12-31 will not be included (unless the order date is 2015-12-31 00:00:00.000. Note how this will skip the first record:

```
DECLARE @orders TABLE (CustomerID INT, orderDate DATETIME);
INSERT @orders VALUES (1, '2015-12-31 00:00:01.000'), (1, '2015-12-30'), (2, '2015-01-04');
SELECT * FROM @orders WHERE orderDate BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31';
```

In this case you would want the WHERE clause filter to look like:

```
WHERE orderDate BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2015-12-31 23:59:59.999';
```

Or

```
WHERE CAST(orderDate AS date) BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31';
```

(the first example will almost certainly perform better).

Now, using this sample data:

```
-- Sample data
CREATE TABLE #LIST (LISTName varchar(10) NOT NULL);
INSERT #LIST 
SELECT TOP (100) LEFT(newid(), 8)
FROM sys.all_columns a, sys.all_columns b;

-- You will probably want LISTName to be indexed
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nc_LISTName ON #LIST(LISTName);
```

You can implement Paul's solution like this:

```
DECLARE @LIST_Param varchar(8) = 'No List';

SELECT LISTName 
FROM 
(
  SELECT distinct LISTName
  FROM #LIST
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'No List'
  WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LISTName) FROM #LIST) < 1000000
) Distinct_LISTName
WHERE (@LIST_Param = 'No List' or @LIST_Param = LISTName);
```

Alternatively you can do this:

```
DECLARE @LIST_Param varchar(8) = 'No List'; 

WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT LISTName, c = COUNT(*)
  FROM #LIST
  WHERE (@LIST_Param = 'No List' or @LIST_Param = LISTName)
  GROUP BY LISTName
),
c AS (SELECT s = SUM(c) FROM x)
SELECT LISTName
FROM x CROSS JOIN c
WHERE s < 1000000;
```